# Multiple double lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two lines with a double appearance:

[image: Two lines]

which I would like to be joined at their intersection:

[image: Joined lines]

(which I did with Object->Path->Join).

However, I don't want the lines to be joined at the end; rather, they should look like:

[image]

I was able to achieve this effect by converting the lines to objects and unioning them, but that makes it very difficult to adjust them later, which I need to do fairly often.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily accomplished by simply adding an additional stroke to the path via the Appearance Panel.

Group the two lines, then add a new stroke in the Appearance Panel and ensure the new stroke is above the `Contents` item in the panel.

[image: group]